# Codename one do something on screen wake

Tags: codenameone

I want to reload my `Form` on screen wake is there any way to do so? The header disappears since we only call the method to create the form with the title once.

Pre screen lock/app switch

[image]

After screen lock/app switch

[image]

Whenever I click one of the menu options the header reappears since we then load a new `Form`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is implicit and you don't need to do it. I'm assuming that you did something else such as disable the `Toolbar` or `setCommandBehavior` which work inconsistently between platforms.

Comment: We don't make use of either in the code. Thanks for the reply though.

Comment: If you don't activate the global toolbar in the init(Object) method then this is the problem. Command behavior can be defined in the theme constants

Comment: I've added `Toolbar.setGlobalToolbar(true)` to the constructor of the class but then I get a totally new and different toolbar. We make use of a `Form` currently without one.

Comment: Without any toolbar? If so just override the method `protected boolean shouldPaintStatusBar()` to return `false`. I'm guessing here without screenshots etc.

Comment: I'll update my question with some screenshots. Thanks for the help thus far!

Comment: That's without the toolbar. Activate the toolbar instead and post the screenshots of the problems you have with the toolbar. This was the native Android toolbar which changed so often it became impractical to support for all use cases.

Comment: Ah I see, it's a legacy project so that makes sense. Thanks for the answer I'll implement a proper toolbar then.

Comment: Actually I do still have a question, we have a more up to date app that looks like is using the same thing. Why does this app not have the problem? See [this image for example](https://i.imgur.com/kLt1xtZ.png)

Comment: Here the title isn't the native OS title as you can see from the color etc. It's probably using command behavior which is also deprecated but more stable.

Comment: Thanks I'll look into it!